# How to write my MS Access query in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a MS Access query which is running fine, but I don't know how to write this query in SQL Server.

MS Access query:-

```
SELECT lp.PortfolioID, 
       Count(IIf(lp.Data_Status = 'Prelim Collection', 1, Null)) AS Prelim_Collection_Cnt, 
       Count(IIf(lp.Data_Status = 'Final Collection', 1, Null)) AS Final_Collection_Cnt, 
       Count(IIf(lp.Data_Status = 'Prelim Entry', 1, Null)) AS Prelim_Entry_Cnt, 
       Count(IIf(lp.Data_Status = 'Final Entry', 1, Null)) AS Final_Entry_Cnt, 
       Count(IIf(lp.Data_Status = 'Prelim QC', 1, Null)) AS Prelim_QC_Cnt, 
       Count(IIf(lp.Data_Status = 'Final QC', 1, Null)) AS Final_QC_Cnt
FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT p.PortfolioID, p.Data_Status 
      FROM Late_Portfolios AS p 
      WHERE p.TimeStamp BETWEEN #10/01/2018# AND #10/31/2018#)  AS lp
GROUP BY lp.PortfolioID;
```

Comment: Have you tried to write it yet?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is switching over to CASE statements as those will work in nearly every RDBMS under the sun (except Access... I can't imagine why it still doesn't support this, but that's MS for you). Other than that, you want to switch your date literals to ISO8601 format `YYYY-MM-DD` and encapsulate them in single quotes instead of hashes.

```
SELECT lp.PortfolioID,  
    COUNT(CASE WHEN lp.Data_Status = 'Prelim Collection' THEN 1 END) AS Prelim_Collection_Cnt, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN lp.Data_Status = 'Final Collection' THEN 1 END) AS Final_Collection_Cnt, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN lp.Data_Status = 'Prelim Entry' THEN 1 END) AS Prelim_Entry_Cnt, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN lp.Data_Status = 'Final Entry' THEN 1 END) AS Final_Entry_Cnt, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN lp.Data_Status = 'Prelim QC' THEN 1 END) AS Prelim_QC_Cnt, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN lp.Data_Status = 'Final QC' THEN 1 END) AS Final_QC_Cnt
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            p.PortfolioID, 
            p.Data_Status 
        FROM Late_Portfolios AS p 
        WHERE p.TimeStamp BETWEEN '2018-10-01' AND '2018-10-31'
    )  AS lp
GROUP BY lp.PortfolioID;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for reply, however in my query I used count function but in your case statement you have not used count function, will it give right answer?

Comment: OMG. I forgot to add that. Just as sec

Comment: Alright. Edited to add that. They could also be switched to `Sum()` to sum up the 1s that are outputted if you so desired.

Comment: Hi JNevill,could you please also solve this below query, that how can I write this query in sql server.

Comment: SELECT lp.PortfolioID, Count(IIf((lp.Data_Status = 'Prelim Collection') OR (lp.Data_Status = 'Final Collection'), 1, Null)) AS Collection_Cnt, Count(IIf((lp.Data_Status = 'Prelim Entry') OR (lp.Data_Status = 'Final Entry'), 1, Null)) AS Entry_Cnt, Count(IIf((lp.Data_Status = 'Prelim QC') OR (lp.Data_Status = 'Final QC'), 1, Null)) AS QC_Cnt
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT p.PortfolioID, p.Data_Status FROM Late_Portfolios AS p WHERE p.TimeStamp BETWEEN #10/01/2018# AND #10/31/2018#)  AS lp
GROUP BY lp.PortfolioID;

Comment: That's like the same query. It's still just a case statement. [Read about them here, they are very easy to write](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Hi JNevill, but here it is using OR condition in, and I don't know how to write in OR statement in CASE statement

Comment: This is a good time to read how to do that. Although.. the format is exactly the same between access and sql, so maybe just try it first.

Answer (score 0):

my parser complained only about your dates, for which you can use 'yyyymmdd'

```
    SELECT lp.PortfolioID, 
        Count(IIf(lp.Data_Status = 'Prelim Collection', 1, Null)) AS Prelim_Collection_Cnt, 
        Count(IIf(lp.Data_Status = 'Final Collection', 1, Null)) AS Final_Collection_Cnt, 
        Count(IIf(lp.Data_Status = 'Prelim Entry', 1, Null)) AS Prelim_Entry_Cnt, 
        Count(IIf(lp.Data_Status = 'Final Entry', 1, Null)) AS Final_Entry_Cnt, 
        Count(IIf(lp.Data_Status = 'Prelim QC', 1, Null)) AS Prelim_QC_Cnt, 
        Count(IIf(lp.Data_Status = 'Final QC', 1, Null)) AS Final_QC_Cnt
    FROM (
                    SELECT DISTINCT p.PortfolioID, 
                                    p.Data_Status 
                                        FROM Late_Portfolios AS p 
                                            WHERE p.TimeStamp BETWEEN '20181001' AND '20181031'
                )  AS lp
     GROUP BY lp.PortfolioID;
```

Comment: `IIF` was only introduced in SQL 2012 and I'm not really sure why because it's awful.

Comment: Thanks for reply, is this same query work in sql server

Comment: @Kashif - are you able to try it?  I think it will work in most SQL Server versions.  I hope one of the versions here works for you.

Comment: @DavidG - IIF was introduced for greater compatibility with Access I heard

Comment: @Cato Possibly, but for me that's another reason why I think it sucks...

Answer (score 0):

The logic should also work in `SQL Server`, if you have a lower version then you can do conditional aggregation instead :

```
select lp.PortfolioID,
       sum(case when lp.Data_Status = 'Prelim Collection' then 1 else 0 end),
from ( <query> )  AS lp
group by lp.PortfolioID;
```

Just pass your date in `20180110` format `ANSI SQL`:

```
where p.TimeStamp >= '20180110' AND p.TimeStamp >= '20181031'
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply, Can I use Count function instead of Sum in sql server 2012.

Comment: @Kashif. . . You can change it accordingly, `count(case when lp.Data_Status = 'Prelim Collection' then 1)`.